# First message to RabbitMQ queue causes channel shutdown

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

The first message to my queue always fails.
From the second one, **everything works just fine!**

[image: Stacktrace]

Not sure if that's readable so :

```
Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#1b940034:0/SimpleConnection@2c52fbff [delegate=amqp://guest@10.0.0.10:5672/, localPort= 36370]

Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'auto_delete' for exchange 'rabbitmq_exchange' in vhost '/': received 'false' but current is 'true', class-id=40, method-id=10)
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, because I launch this on a fresh VM (AWS EC2 instance) every single time. How could "current be true"?

I suppose something is badly configured in the Spring Boot publisher:

[image]

Not sure if that's readable so :

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMqConfig {
    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(System.getenv("RABBITMQ_QUEUE_NAME"), true,false, false);
    }

    @Bean
    DirectExchange exchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(System.getenv("RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME"), true, false);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(System.getenv("RABBITMQ_ROUTING_KEY"));
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter(){
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    public AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
}
```

So what's going wrong here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is quite clear...

> Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'auto_delete' for exchange 'rabbitmq_exchange' in vhost '/': received 'false' but current is 'true', class-id=40, method-id=10)

When the connection is first opened, the framework looks for queues/bindings etc and declares them. If a queue exists already, it must have the same properties/arguments.

```
@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(System.getenv("RABBITMQ_QUEUE_NAME"), true, false, false);
}
```

Presumably, on the consumer side, it is being declared with different properties...

```
@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(System.getenv("RABBITMQ_QUEUE_NAME"), true, false, true);
}
```

(the auto_delete is inequivalent).

They must be the same.

Comment: Yes my knowledge of RabbitMQ is quite limited. Explicitly setting the autoDelete and durable option on my Apache Camel consuming route did it for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Define a queue as below.

```
declare queue name=YourQueName durable=false --vhost="YourVirtualHostName" -u UsernameOfYourQueue -p PasswordOfYourQueue
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the queue was first created with wrong configurations, so each time I relaunched my application this error where shown.
Deleting the queue and letting the application recreated it, with the new configurations, solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't exactly get this message, however Port was getting closed every time I try sending message. I was able to find the issue to virtual-host, I didn't point to the correct VHost the account had permission on.

Adding this entry to `application.properties` fixed the issue.

`spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host=<correct-vhost>`